# Localize the calendar without changing the language of the wordpress website

Tags: php, wordpress, calendar

1) I setting timezone Wordpress 4.9.4 in **Settings > General** like this:

```
Timezone: Jakarta
Date Format: j F Y
Time Format: H:i
```

2) I have Indonesian calendar time function code from [this](http://abetobing.com/blog/function-indonesian-date-untuk-menampilkan-tanggal-dalam-format-indonesia-49.html):

```
function indonesian_date ($timestamp = '', $date_format = 'l, j F Y | H:i', $suffix = 'WIB') {
    if (trim ($timestamp) == '')
    {
        $timestamp = time ();
    }
    elseif (!ctype_digit ($timestamp))
    {
        $timestamp = strtotime ($timestamp);
    }
    # remove S (st,nd,rd,th) there are no such things in indonesia :p
    $date_format = preg_replace ("/S/", "", $date_format);
    $pattern = array (
        '/Mon[^day]/','/Tue[^sday]/','/Wed[^nesday]/','/Thu[^rsday]/',
        '/Fri[^day]/','/Sat[^urday]/','/Sun[^day]/','/Monday/','/Tuesday/',
        '/Wednesday/','/Thursday/','/Friday/','/Saturday/','/Sunday/',
        '/Jan[^uary]/','/Feb[^ruary]/','/Mar[^ch]/','/Apr[^il]/','/May/',
        '/Jun[^e]/','/Jul[^y]/','/Aug[^ust]/','/Sep[^tember]/','/Oct[^ober]/',
        '/Nov[^ember]/','/Dec[^ember]/','/January/','/February/','/March/',
        '/April/','/June/','/July/','/August/','/September/','/October/',
        '/November/','/December/',
    );
    $replace = array ( 'Sen','Sel','Rab','Kam','Jum','Sab','Min',
        'Senin','Selasa','Rabu','Kamis','Jumat','Sabtu','Minggu',
        'Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','Mei','Jun','Jul','Ags','Sep','Okt','Nov','Des',
        'Januari','Februari','Maret','April','Juni','Juli','Agustus','Sepember',
        'Oktober','November','Desember',
    );
    $date = date ($date_format, $timestamp);
    $date = preg_replace ($pattern, $replace, $date);
    $date = "{$date} {$suffix}";
    return $date;
}
```

3) Code for show it calendar:

```
<?php
$timestamp = current_time( 'timestamp', true );
echo indonesian_date($timestamp, 'l, j F Y | H:i', 'WIB');
?>
```

**My Problem:**
The calendar time show: Senin, 19 Maret 2018 | 23:15 WIB
Should be like this: Senin, 19 Maret 2018 | 06:15 WIB

There is a difference in clock calculation, 23:15 WIB and 06:15 WIB. What should I fix to existing code?

Comment: Have you had a look at PHPs Intl-extension? I'm pretty sure the IntlDateFotmatter does what you are trying there already. And what does the time look like when you do *not* modify it? The timestamp is per definition UTC so probably you need to set the timezone correctly. It might be easier to donthst when you use the DateTime-class.

Comment: heiglandreas, thank for your advice.